# Как прочитать цвет пикселя в картинке на C++ с помощью библиотеки fstream

Tags: c++, изображения, fstream

Задача: Есть файл png, необходимо записать эту картинку попиксельно в двумерный массив - в каждой ячейке которого должен быть цвет одного пикселя в трёх каналах RGB.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class image {

private:
    static int id;

    class pixel {
    public:
        int R = 0;
        int G = 0;
        int B = 0;

        pixel();
        pixel (int R, int G, int B);
    };

pixel** picture = nullptr;

public:

image(int X, int Y, string path);

};

int main() {

    return 0;
}

image::pixel::pixel () {
R = 255; 
G = 255; 
B = 255;
}

image::pixel::pixel (int R, int G, int B) {
this->R = R;
this->G = G;
this->B = B;
}

image::image (int X, int Y, string path) {
picture = new pixel * [X];
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
    picture[i] = new pixel[Y];
}

ofstream pic(path, ios::binary);

}
```

Comment: 1) написать парсер формата png 2) написать декомпрессор LZV 3) использовать парсер и декомпрессор для распаковки бинарных данных, читаемых через `ofstream`

Comment: Картинки проще парсить готовой библиотекой, скажем `stb_image`.

Comment: @VTT конечно имел ввиду `ifstream`...

Comment: Нужно больше информации. Windows? Linux? QT? VS?

Comment: Я работаю под Windows